# Asp.net core 3.0 - combining identity authentication with challenge scheme

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

The following code worked alright before adding Identity framework to allow users to register and login.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
  {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "External Provider";
  })
```

User authentication will only work if shown as

```
services.AddAuthentication()
```

How can I now combine identity framework authentication and challenge scheme to work in conjunction?

Answer (score 0):

How did you use your identity?

I use **AddDefaultIdentity** with your code and have the same problem.

If you used that, then there will be two default authentication scheme while we can only have one,

that's why the identity can't be used after we add **DefaultAuthenticateScheme**.

To add Cookie, you can use this way instead:

```
//services.AddDefaultIdentity....
services.AddAuthentication(...).AddCookie(...);
```

Following link is a demo, you can check it:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cookie-authentication-in-net-core-3-0/